# Array's first character gets populated with incorrect data C++

Tags: c++, arrays, global

In a header file, I declare a struct with an array and array length like so:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char *frame;
    int length;
} ResponseFrame ;

extern ResponseFrame rf;
```

In my main file, I have the following:

```
ResponseFrame rf;

int main(void)
{
   while(1) {
      if (receive() == 0x01) {
         uint8_t val;
         rf.length = 6;
         for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            val = receive();
            rf.frame[i] = val;
            transmit(val);            // LINE 1
         }


         for (uint8_t i=0; i<rf.length; i++){
            transmit(rf.frame[i]);    // LINE 2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The array I'm receiving is

```
{ 00 00 FF 00 FF 00 }
```

The initial transmit responds with this received data [see LINE 1] .
However, when I try to transmit using the global variable rf.frame [see LINE 2], the first value is different like this ----

```
{ 13 00 FF 00 FF 00 }
```

Why is that first initial value different like this??

Comment: You're a declaring a struct with a unsigned char pointer, not with an array

Comment: where is receive and transmit ?And also what happens when at Line 1 transmit(val); is replaced with  transmit(rf.frame[i]); ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocate any memory for `ResponseFrame.frame`, so you're running into undefined behaviour.

You're assuming that by doing `rf.length = 6;`, the size of `unsigned char *frame;` somehow magically increases, but it doesn't.

If you're certain of the size, you need:

```
rf.length = 6;
rf.frame = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 6);   //for C
```

or use a `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: Actually, in C++ usually you would just use a plain `std::vector<unsigned char>` and forget about the problem.

Comment: and it's C++, not C. I'll use the std::vector<unsigned char> --- lots to learn! :P

Comment: if he hasn't allocated memory how is he able to run the code??? for rf.frame=0 (Assuming initialized with zero), and setting value at *rf.frame that is *0, without access violation????/

Comment: @Anonymous undefined behaviour doesn't guarantee a crash. It's probably unused memory, you'd get an access violation if the memory was in use. But anything can happen.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: still, it's quite strange, because, being `rf` a global, it's zero initialized. This means that `frame` should be `NULL`, which, on any sensible architecture, segfaults when used.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem might be that it appears to be relying on undefined behavior.  It appears (from the shown code) that `frame` is never initialized.  If it is a fixed size, it could be declared as:

```
unsigned char frame[6];
```

Otherwise, it may need a call to `malloc` to allocate memory for it.